# Can I always avoid using cmake or make when building projects?

Tags: c++, compilation, cmake, makefile

Often to build library when you get the source code, you're asked to build it with a cmake command. Sometimes it happens that framework ask you to build your code with cmake too (for example Qt).

I'm currently using Qt for a personal project and I am totally able to compile with it a good batch file. 
So, is it always possible to avoid using cmake ? Or should I definitively learn to get over it at some point ?

Comment: Why would you not just use the build system the implementer provides? You should definitely use it, it might do non-trivial stuff in the background. I also see no problem with using CMake.

Comment: cmake, qmake, autofoo, bakefile, scons...all are good, pick one that fits you needs

Answer (score 6):

The goal of make/cmake is precisely to **avoid** using batch scripts to compile your program.

- Make let you execute shell commands, but comes with built-in dependency resolution, and check whether each target needs to be rebuilt. It also handle multi threaded compilation (assuming you wrote your `Makefile` correctly)
- CMake does everything make does, but also comes with tons of goodies like portability, very good support of C/C++, and `find_package`, which is definitely a must-have feature.

In the long run, you will save a lot of time and avoid a lot of troubles by using a good build system.

Answer (score 1):

CMake, make and all those other build tools just execute a sequence of commands. If you can replicate the commands without actually calling CMake, then you will get the same end result.

BUT... those tools are used by developers for a reason. Typically the sequence of commands varies from system to system in non-trivial ways. The build system will prevent rebuild of unchanged components, and ensure changed ones are rebuilt.

So you can do it your way, but you should still get over your avoidance of build-systems and embrace them for the time savers they are.